# Avoid redis processes to make RDB snapshots on the same time

Tags: redis

Imagine setup of Redis Cluster for example, or just usual sharded setup, where we have N > 1 Redis processes per physical node. All our processes have same redis.conf and enabled SAVE options there with same SAVE period. So, if all our main Redis processes started on the same time - all of them will start SAVE on the same time or around it.
When we have 9 Redis processes and all of them start RDB snapshotting on the same time it:

1. Affects performance, because we make 9 forked processes that start consume CPU and do IO on the same time.
2. Requires too much reserved additional memory that can't be used as actual storage, because on write-heavy application Redis may use up to 2x the memory normally used during snapshotting. So... if we want to have redis processes for 100Gb on this node - we should take additional 100Gb for forking all processes on the same time to be safe.

Is there any best practice to modify this setup and make Redis processes start saving one by one or at least with some randomization?

I have only one idea with disabling schedule in redis.conf and write cron script that will start save one by one with time lag. But this solution looks like a hack and it should be some other practices here.

Comment: I think you have the right idea in your last paragraph. Disable persistence in the config files and manually call BGSAVE from a scheduler (e.g cron).